# How to redirect from button to my play store page?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want my users able to press "Other Games" button, and redirect them to my developer play store page via Google play app. 
I did it as following, but it redirected incorrectly.

```
final String appPackageName2 = "MyCompany%20Name"; // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
     try {
           activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://developer?id=" + appPackageName2)));
     } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
           activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=" + appPackageName2)));
     }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "redirected incorrectly" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the developer page is different, look at an example:

```
final String developer_id = "my_dev_id";

try {

  activity.startActivity(
    new Intent(
      Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
      Uri.parse("market://dev?id=" + developer_id)
    )
  );

} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

  activity.startActivity(
    new Intent(
      Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
      Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/dev?id=" + developer_id)
    )
  );

}
```

To get the information visit your [developer page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6226441), there you will find all information about your id and other things. Luck.

Docs: [Link to Google Play](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play.html)